# How to convert a string into float value?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I want to convert a value height into float value. The final value is 3 ft 5 in. I want to convert it into float value 3.5 in C#. This value varies in my formula and I need to use it for calculation. How to do this task?

Comment: so the string will **always** look like "... ft ... in"?

Comment: yes. but i dont need units.

Comment: are you aware of the fact that 12 inches are 1 foot? :D so "3 ft 6 in" would be 3.5 ;)

Comment: What do you want for `3 ft 11 in`? `3.11`? What is your purpose because surely you're not trying to do math here

Comment: Wow instead of getting many answers i am getting negative points.

Comment: @madhukumar That's what happens when you post a question that doesn't make sense and don't answer clarifying questions.

Comment: @madhukumar could you please clarify whether you need the data converted based on the units of whether you just need the string formatted as `{0}.{1}`? My answer appears to be considered wrong - however, given how you have asked the question it's *technically* correct.

Comment: @James no need of conversion. remove "ft" and "in". just combine them into float value. that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your input string is called `input`:

```
var parts = input.Trim().Split(' ');
int feet = int.Parse(parts[0]);
int inches = int.Parse(parts[2]);
float result = feet + inches / 12.0f;
```

But be aware that this is dirty (depends on spacing, etc.) - since you did not provide any further detail about what you are given and what you want (or rather what I am very sure you want - look at comments below your question), this is as far as you can get. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that 3ft 5in is not 3.5 feet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string heightString = "3ft 5 in";
        string validRegex = @"^\d(\s)*ft(\s)*\d(\s)*in$";
        if(!Regex.Match(heightString, validRegex).Success)
            throw new Exception("Invalid Input");

        var feetIndex = heightString.IndexOf("ft");
        var substring = heightString.Substring(0,feetIndex ).Trim();
        var inchesSubString = heightString.Substring(feetIndex + 2);
        var inchesStr = inchesSubString.Substring(0, inchesSubString.IndexOf("in")).Trim();

        var integralPart = float.Parse(substring);
        var fractionalPart = float.Parse(inchesStr)/10D;

        var result = integralPart + fractionalPart;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is always of format "3 ft 5 in", you can split by space, concatenate the first and third item along with a "." in between and convert the resulting string to a float.

```
    public float Convert(string height)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(height))
            return 0;

        // input format: "3 ft 5 in"
        var spaceSplitted = height.Split(' ');
        if (spaceSplitted.Length <= 3)
            return 0;

        var concatenatedValue = spaceSplitted[0] + "." + spaceSplitted[2];

        float floatResult;

        float.TryParse(concatenatedValue, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out floatResult);

        return floatResult;
    }
```

Comment: Should always Use `double` in java, float is not as accurate